# SOLR 7.2 Back up and restore

Tags: solr, backup, restore

I have a SOLR 7.2 cloud with 6 nodes fronted by a DNS/F5. I have over 80 GB of indexed data in these nodes. I want to create a back-up of this index as a starting point before my indexes change through my regular business transactions. I also want to restore this backed up index to a different data center for resiliency and DR purposes. Few questions

1) Do I have to run the BACKUP Collections API command on each SOLR node? What if I directly use the F5/DNS to BACKUP the collections? Will solr create the correct backups? 
2) I understand that the BACKUP could be created on a shared drive. However, a shared drive in one data center may not be visible to another data center that could be in a complete different subnet. Any ideas?
3) While restoring the collection do I have to use the exact collection name or I can generate a new one? I am assuming that the configs from the source collection will be used to generate the new collection in the target Data center.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You run the [BACKUP Collection command](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-backup) on one node. If you send it to your load balancer, it should still work as each node will receive the request distributed internally. All nodes will have to have access to the same shared network store in the same local location.

After making the backup, transfer the backed up content to an accessible location in the new data center. How you do this will depend on how your data centers are able to communicate, but rsync and ssh are the usual suspects. There's no way to make data magically travel between isolated networks.

When you [restore a backed up collection](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-backup) you provide the name you want the collection restored as to the command as the `collection` parameter:

```
/admin/collections?action=RESTORE&name=myBackupName&location=/path/to/my/shared/drive&collection=myRestoredCollectionName
```

You can also override parts of the existing settings when restoring the backup. For 7.2 these parameters are `collection.configName`, `replicationFactor`, `maxShardsPerNode`, `autoAddReplicas` and any custom property through `property.<name>=value`.

For other Solr versions consider the reference guide for that specific version (although I think that list is valid for most currently used versions).

Comment: I tried using the load balancer to do that. I don't see that the collections API generates a distributed query to each shard master and generate a backup. The back up for just a single shard was created. I am not sure if SOLR does that internally. The support documentation is really weak. Is the backup created for each master node and then during restore it is replicated to each shard. OR. Is a backup for all replicas created and then restored back. Any information will be appreciated.

Comment: The documentation explicitly states that it will back up the entire collection. _The BACKUP command takes **one copy from each shard** for the indexes. For configurations, it backs up the configSet that was associated with the collection and metadata._

Comment: Thanks for the information. If I have 3 shards, will I see 3 different backup shards ? Or is it  one big backup set that gets created? I tried to use the F5 to create the backup using the Collections API and I could see only one server in the cluster get the backup index. Not even sure if this is the entire backup or just a backup of the index owned by that server. I was hoping to see one aggregated set of backup, which can be restored anywhere.